# How to send a python bytearray into solidity function by web3.py?

Tags: transactions, web3.py, python

I have a solidity function declared as:

```
function setUnitData(bytes32[10] my_input_array) public payable {...}
```

When I run this code:

```
contract = self.contract_instance['../contracts/test.sol:test']

test_byte = b'0x01234567890123456789012345678901' * 24
tx_hash = contract.functions.setUnitData(test_byte).transact({'from': self.w3.toChecksumAddress(unit['update_account']), 'gas': 3400000})
```

I get this `ValidationError`:

> web3.exceptions.ValidationError: 
>       Could not identify the intended function with name `setUnitData`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'bytes'>,)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
>   Found 1 function(s) with the name `setUnitData`: ['setUnitData(bytes32[10])']
>   Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

Any possible or best way to send the python byte array or any workable type to this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `setUnitData(bytes32[10])` requires an array of 10 elements, each of which is 32 bytes of data. Since we don't know the purpose of the function, let's generate a some random data of that type:

```
>>> input_array = [bytes(range(idx, 32 + idx)) for idx in range(10)]
[b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f',
 b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f ',
 b'\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !',
 b'\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"',
 b'\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#',
 b'\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$',
 b'\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%',
 b'\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&',
 b'\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'',
 b'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'(']
```

If looking at native bytes values in python makes you grumpy, you can convert to hex strings. Web3.py will accept either.

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> hex_array = [Web3.toHex(bytes_data) for bytes_data in input_array] 
['0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f',
 '0x0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f20',
 '0x02030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021',
 '0x030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122',
 '0x0405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f20212223',
 '0x05060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021222324',
 '0x060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425',
 '0x0708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f20212223242526',
 '0x08090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021222324252627',
 '0x090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728']
```

Now you can send a transaction with:

```
contract = self.contract_instance['../contracts/test.sol:test']
tx_hash = contract.functions.setUnitData(input_array).transact({'from': self.w3.toChecksumAddress(unit['update_account']), 'gas': 3400000})
```

(`hex_array` also works, in place of `input_array`)

Comment: It returns following error: `Could not decode contract function call getJobStorageTime return data b''` @carver

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of bytes. The cntract is expecting an array of 10 elements but you are passing a bytes variable. You can create an array with all the other elements set to zeros.

Hope this helps